# Securing Cloud Functions auth onDelete trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

How do we secure the auth().onDelete handler so it's not exposed as a function (so user code cannot call it)?

I define the handler as a Firebase Cloud function:

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user, context) => { ... }
```

It seems like this function is executable in client code by calling:

```
var f = config.getFunctions().httpsCallable('deleteUser')
const rc = await f({user: 'abc'})
```

I want that code to fail as if the function does not exist, but it doesn't. Running "firebase serve" I see the function being executed when I call it directly using the httpsCallable approach.

I want to ensure it's automatically called when a user is deleted but never otherwise.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I see the function being executed"?

Comment: On the console where I have "firebase serve" running I see the console.log output from my deleteUser function when I execute the code:

 var f = config.getFunctions().httpsCallable('deleteUser')
const rc = await f({user: 'abc'})

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the emulator.  That won't happen when the function is deployed.  If it does, file a bug.